# Changing all Keys of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, array-map

I have an array called `$row`:

```
$row = array(
    "comments" => "this is a test comment", 
    "current_path" => "testpath"
)
```

I have another array called `$dictionary`:

```
$dictionary= array(
    "comments" => "comments", 
    "current_directory" => "current_path"
)
```

I want to change the keys in `$row` to the key associated with the matching value in `$dictionary`.

For example, in the case above, `$row` would become:

```
$row = array(
    "comments" => "this is a test comment", 
    "current_directory" => "testpath"
)
```

I have tried using `array_map` but this doesn't seem to be changing anything:

```
array_map(function($key) use ($dictionary){
  return array_search($key, $dictionary);
}, array_keys($row));
```

How would I change the key properly?

Note from comment:

> Unfortunately, there will generally be more entries in $dictionary then $row and the order cannot be guaranteed

Comment: Can the dictionary be inverted?

Comment: @tereško unfortunately no

Comment: @tereško Although I could use `array_flip` on a copy of the `$dictionary` I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$dictionary` can be flipped, then

```
$dictionary = array_flip($dictionary);

$result = array_combine(
    array_map(function($key) use ($dictionary){ 
        return $dictionary[$key]; 
    }, array_keys($row)),
    $row
);
```

If not, then you will be better off doing a manual loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple potential "gotcha"s in the solution for your case.  Since your two arrays might not have equal size, you will have to use `array_search()` inside a loop.  Also, though it seems unlikely for your case, I would like to mention that if `$dictionary` has the keys: `"0"` or `0` then `array_search()`'s return value must be strictly checked for `false`.  Here is the method that I recommend:

Input:

```
$row=array(
    "comments"=>"this is a test comment", 
    "title"=>"title text",                      // key in $row not a value in $dictionary
    "current_path"=>"testpath"
);

$dictionary=array(
    "0"=>"title",                               // $dictionary key equals zero (falsey)
    "current_directory"=>"current_path",
    "comments"=>"comments", 
    "bogus2"=>"bogus2"                          // $dictionary value not a key in $row
);
```

Method ([Demo](https://ideone.com/iSpdrV)):

```
foreach($row as $k=>$v){
    if(($newkey=array_search($k,$dictionary))!==false){  // if $newkey is not false
        $result[$newkey]=$v;                    // swap in new key
    }else{
        $result[$k]=$v;                         // no key swap, store unchanged element
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'comments' => 'this is a test comment',
  0 => 'title text',
  'current_directory' => 'testpath',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a manual loop and output to a new variable.
You cant use array_map or array_walk to change the structure of an array.

```
<?php
   $row = ["comments" =>"test1", "current_path" => "testpath"];

   $dict = ["comments" => "comments", "current_directory" => "current_path"];

    foreach($row as $key => $value){
       $row2[array_search($key, $dict)] = $value;
   };

  var_dump($row2);

 ?>
```